# disable autofocus in android camerax (camera 2)

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, android-camera2, android-camerax

I'm in project of scanning barcode, so i want to disable auto-focus for improving performance. I tried so many ways but it doesn't work at all. Could anyone give me some help? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using a library for barcode scanning? If so which?

Comment: i'm using google mlkit for scanning

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want to turn off AF, you can do this on CameraX with the `Camera2CameraControl` class. To do this you have to first bind the use cases you need to the lifecycle which results in a `Camera` object, you can then use that camera object to get the `CameraControl` object and then use it to instantiate a `Camera2CameraControl` which would let you set the focus mode to `CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF`.

```kt
    val camera : Camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                        this,
                        cameraSelector,
                        imagePreview,
                        imageCapture,
                        imageAnalysis
                    )
    
    val cameraControl : CameraControl = camera.cameraControl
    val camera2CameraControl : Camera2CameraControl = Camera2CameraControl.from(cameraControl)
    
    //Then you can set the focus mode you need like this
    val captureRequestOptions = CaptureRequestOptions.Builder()
                .setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_MODE_OFF)
                .build()
            camera2CameraControl.captureRequestOptions = captureRequestOptions
```

This was tested on the latest CameraX's "1.0.0-rc03" build.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I thought I'd have to resort to using Camera2 again to get a more fine grained control over the camera settings. Thanks!

Comment: Super solution, thank you! You can also use the CaptureRequestOptions to set the focus distance manually and other things.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
disableAutoCancel()
```

with cameraX 1.0.0. The camera focuses once then stays locked, autofocus is not restarted at every X seconds, so something like

```
    val autoFocusAction = FocusMeteringAction.Builder(
                    autoFocusPoint,
                    FocusMeteringAction.FLAG_AF or
                            FocusMeteringAction.FLAG_AE or
                            FocusMeteringAction.FLAG_AWB
                ).apply {
                            disableAutoCancel()      
                    }
                }.build()
    
myCameraControl!!.startFocusAndMetering(autoFocusAction)
```